# Remote Server Configuration

Tags: linux, networking, ip, router, nas

I have a NAS Server on my network.

Recently, there was a power cut in my area, and when the router came back up, the LAN IP of my server remained the same, but the remote IP of my server was changed. This would be problematic for accessing my server from a remote location if it happens while I'm out and about.

Would it be possible to set a persistent static **REMOTE** IP for my server, or is this an issue that I'd just have to put up with?

Answer (score 2):

You should talk with your ISP about static IP for you. Or use services like dyndns, noip, etc. These services (if you can install client on NAS or other running computer in your local network) will provide static hostname with dynamic public IP.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I'll look into it. I'm very grateful :)

I'd cast a 1-up for your answer, but I'm relatively new to Stack Overflow and the associated sites. It's saying I need at least 15 reputation to do so.

Comment: @Lee, **when** you are happy with my answer you can accept it (tick on the left of the answer)